# What is the purpose of the dirty coin?

Tags: resident-evil-7

In the demo for the game, which is called Resident Evil 7 Beginning Hour, by fulfilling certain requirements you are able to obtain a 'dirty coin' which can then be transferred over to the main game.

What is the use of the dirty coin in the main game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be used in place of an Antique Coin to open bird cages and get upgrades. Most importantly, you have it from the beginning of the game, giving you a head start on gaining upgrades.

Comment: hmmm... I haven't got to the birdcages yet. I feel that as there are a limited number of coins anyway, does it really make that much difference having one extra from the start? (and ending with one spare at the end) I guess it might become more useful on madhouse mode perhaps